# JQuery: Click a random link on document ready

Tags: jquery, random, click

I have five links on a page which display different content on another part of the page when clicked. Each link has an ID and I have a simple click function on document ready to select the first link:

$('#link1').click();

How can I have it click one of the five links at random on document ready, instead of #link1 specifically? And yes, I realize that a click function probably isn't the ideal way to handle this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smoov jQuery way of doing things:

```
jQuery.jQueryRandom = 0;
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[":"], {
  random: function(a, i, m, r) {
     if (i == 0) {
         jQuery.jQueryRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length);
     };
     return i == jQuery.jQueryRandom;
 } });

<script type="text/javascript">
 $().ready(function() {
     alert($("a:random").click());
 }); 
 </script>
```

(I knew about custom selectors, but still shamelessly stolen from [here](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/))

Slightly less smoov:

```
$(function() {
   var links = $('a');
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length)  
   links.get(randomNumber).click();
}
```

If you want links with an ID that start with link, you can always do:

```
   var links = $("a[id^='link']");
```

And now it doesn't matter whether you use numbers or whatever. Anything that has an ID that starts with link. (naturally, you could apply it to a particular css class too)

Comment: +1 I threw up in my mouth a little, and then I swooned. Awesome.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much and thanks to everyone else who answered.

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*5)
$($('a').get(randomnumber)).click();
```

Comment: Better use `.eq()`: `$('a').eq(randomnumber).click();`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the links of interest start with 'link' followed by a number:

```
$('a[id="link' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + '"]')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be

```
links = new Array();
$('a').each(function() { links.push($(this)) });
el = links[Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length)]
el.click();
```

That grabs all the links on the page and puts them into an array and then clicks on one of them.

Comment: There is no need to put them in an array first.

Comment: I broke it out so he could see the process and not just copy and paste code.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible hack:

```
$('a[href^="link"]').sort(function(){return Math.random()-0.5}).eq(0).click()
```

The above code will shuffle the links, and return the first one.
Then you can trigger 'click' of the returned element